# Can Kitkat HCE(NFC) device talk to another Kitkat HCE(NFC) device

Tags: java, android, nfc, hce

Can Kitkat HCE(NFC) device talk to another Kitkat HCE(NFC) device?

I want to write apps to transfer data from one Kitkat HCE(NFC) device  to another Kitkat HCE(NFC) device.

If code is already present

Answer (score 1):

What you ask does not make much sense. If both devices operate in card emulation mode, then they can't communicate directly with each other.

NFC has three operating modes:

1. *Reader/writer mode:* NFC device can read/write NFC tags and interact with contactless smartcards.
2. *Peer-to-peer mode:* Two NFC device can communicate directly with each other.
3. *Card emulation mode (either with secure element or through software card emulation/HCE):* NFC device acts as contactless smartcard and can therefore interact with legacy contactless smartcard readers (or NFC devices in reader/writer mode).

Thus if one of the devices should use Android HCE, then the other device would need to operate in reader/writer mode. As Android devices would use peer-to-peer mode (specifically SNEP over LLCP) by default, the other device would also need to be a device with Android 4.4+. That second device would then need to disable peer-to-peer mode and card emulation mode and explicitly put the NFC interface in reader/writer mode *only*. This can be done through Android's [reader-mode API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#enableReaderMode%28android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29).